# Best choice to store data of input that the application will remember it after the restart

Tags: java, database, file, project

I'm creating an application where students can check their grades, subjects, calendar. They will be able to add new grades, subjects, events from the future. And right now I don't have an idea. What is the best way to store that date, as the list of grades than program after restart will remember that data?

Would save to file method be good enough for beginner programmer? :)

Here's an example of my code (how you see I'm saveing data in objects and objects in lists)

**Classbook.java**

```
Map<String, Subject> subjects = new HashMap<>();

public void addSubject(String name, String lecturer, String room) {
    Subject subject = new Subject(name, lecturer, room);
    subjects.put(name, subject);
}

public void addGrade(String SubjectName, double grade, String forWhat, String type) {
    subjects.get(SubjectName).addGrade(grade, forWhat, type);
}
```

**Subject.java**

```
Map<String, Grade> grades = new HashMap<>();

public void addGrade(double grade, String forWhat, String name) {
    Grade newGrade = new Grade(grade, forWhat);
    grades.put(name, newGrade);
}
```

**Grade.java**

```
public class Grade extends Subject {

double grade = 0;
String forWhat = "";

Grade(double grade, String forWhat) {
    setForWhat(forWhat);
    setGrade(grade);
}

public double getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(double grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getForWhat() {
    return forWhat;
}

public void setForWhat(String forWhat) {
    this.forWhat = forWhat;
}

}
```

Comment: Not necessarily best, but a fairly simple one is to use Java's serialization. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: Grade shouldn't extend subject. Avoid inheritance and use composition where possible.

Comment: Oh You'r right! I forgot to delete this after rewrite this class. But thanks I didn't notice that  I will look at serialization, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert an object representing all the application data to something that can be written and read from the file system.

Instead of using native Java serialization I'd suggest to use JSON. You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. This will require a tiny bit more work but will let you visually inspect the data once it's saved as JSON is human readable.

```
public class State {
  private Map<String, Grade> grades = new HashMap<>();
  private Map<String, Subject> subjects = new HashMap<>();
  ...
}

State st. = new State();
st.addGrade(...);
String json = new Gson().toJson(st);
```

If you want to try something more challenging go for [H2 database](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) but this will require understanding SQL or ORM to map the relations into objects.

Comment: Ok, I will look at it, thanks. I love challenges, so the tougher the better! :D

Comment: Fortunately I understand SQL, so maybe after dealing with JSON I will go for H2 database. :) Thanks again!